# How to make Git checkout necessary commits in submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep commit | while read _1 _2 ID PATH; do 
     (cd $PATH; git checkout $ID;)
done
```

I suspect there should be normal Git command for this, including to do it recursively for nested submodules.

How to do it in normal way?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's just plain `git submodule update`.